# In spring batch is there a way to force the execution to a step if the skip limit has been surpassed

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a simple batch process with a skip limit set.  When the skip limit is surpassed the job fails and it never gets to step two.  I would like the process to go to step 3 if the skip limit has passed.

```
<job id="jobA" incrementer="runIdIncrementer" >
    <step id="step1" next="step2">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk commit-interval="10"  reader="dReader" writer="dWriter" skip-limit="100">
                <skippable-exception-classes>
                    <include class="java.lang.Exception"/>
                </skippable-exception-classes>
            </chunk>
            <listeners>
                <listener ref="skipListener"/>
            </listeners>
        </tasklet>
    </step>
    <step id="step2" next="step3">
        <tasklet>
            <chunk commit-interval="10"  reader="sReader" writer="sWriter"/>
        </tasklet>
    </step>     
    <step id="step3">
        <tasklet ref="cleanUpStep"/>
    </step>
</job>
```

Is there a way to do this? I have tried setting "next" but an error is thrown stating cant have next attribute and a transition element.

Any help would be great.

Comment: skip-limit is binded on a LimitCheckingItemSkipPolicy. Maybe you can try to inject a custom one that intercept and suppress SkipLimitExceededException

Comment: I believed you followed the http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#conditionalFlow ? What is the error thrown exactly ?

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci Thanks I will try that. 
Asoub yes I tried following that but got the error mentioned in the post "cant have next attribute and a transition element. "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix it using "next".  I was including next attribute while also having 
`next="step2"` set in the step declaration.  The fix was to remove this from here and then you can add in the next attribute.

```
<step id="step1">
    <tasklet>
        <chunk commit-interval="10"  reader="dReader" writer="dWriter" skip-limit="100">
            <skippable-exception-classes>
                <include class="java.lang.Exception"/>
            </skippable-exception-classes>
        </chunk>
        <listeners>
            <listener ref="skipListener"/>
        </listeners>
    </tasklet>
<next on="*" to="step2" />
</step>
```

The above code will continue to step2 even if the skip limit has been reached. `<step id="step1" next="step2">` would cause the job to fail if the limit was reached.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `StepExecutionListener` to your step. The `afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution)` will be executed even if the step failed. In this method, you can get the exit status of the step and change it: `stepExecution.setExitStatus(ExitStatus.COMPLETED)`.

You might want to check if the error comes from the skip-limit being exceeded, maybe `stepExecution.getFailureExceptions()` and search for `SkipLimitExceededException` (or something like that). You could also get the number of skiped item and compare it with your max (However, if it's an `Error` on the 100's skip, maybe you should do something else ...)

Note: Skipping a step after having too much exceptions doesn't sound like good design, but as long as you're aware of what you're doing ...

Comment: Hi thanks for your response.  I tried this but the job still fails and it never continues on to the other steps if the skip limit is reached.